# making routes in node js with MVC

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am new to backend programming and I am trying to route my application which is built on nodejs and expressjs but. I first built it without using the 'Router()' in express but now am trying to integrate it together with MVC and I am encountering some issues.

This is a snippet of the code that is supposed to route to /storePost:

.... in the index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

...

var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);

...
```

...in the admin.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
...

var bookController = require('../controllers/bookController');

...

router.get('/createBook', bookController.book_create);
router.post('/storeBook' , bookController.book_store);

...
module.exports = router
```

...in the bookController.js file

```
var Book = require('../database/models/Book');
...

var book_store = (req, res) => {
    try{
        var { file } = req.files;
       
        file.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'public/uploads', file.name), (error) => {
            console.log('File loaded to server');
        
            Book.create({
                ...req.body,
                file: `/books/${file.name}`
            }, (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        res.redirect('/displayBook');
                    });
        });   
    }catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

...

module.exports = {
   ...
   book_store: book_store,
   ...
}
```

And this is the few the application is supposed to route from:

```
@layout('layouts.admin');

@section('content')

<div class="container p-2 m-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8-md offset-2">
            <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/storeBook" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                ...
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="submit">Create Book</button>
              </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>

</style>
<br>
<br>
@endsection
```

The app is running on MongoDB/mongoose for the database.
Here is the error the application is throwing: Cannot Post /storeBook.

Comment: Please explain the issues, and did you export the router in admin.js?

Comment: There is no route called `storePost`. Did you mean `storeBook`?

Comment: The issue is I am not able to access the routes I defined in the admin.js file. The application cant seem to access the POST request route.

Comment: @Christian I meant ```storeBook``` not ```storePost```. Thank you!

Comment: Are you exporting the router from admin.js?

Comment: @Christian Yes, I am exporting the router from admin.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are making mistake.
you should send POST request to /admin/storeBook NOT /storeBook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
app.use('/admin/', adminRouter);
```

add / after admin